# Programmatically edit the properties of build.prop on Android

Tags: java, android, file-io

I would like to know whether it is possible or not to open the build.prop file programmatically from an Android application and edit certain properties within it. Are there certain restrictions on this file in Android and can it be done without root access?

If someone could point me in the right direction or provide and example that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ROOT permission is required to open and edit build.prop file.

Check this App in Play Store. [build.prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nathan.jf.build.prop.editor&hl=en). Since it's open source, and the code is extremely simple, you can use it as a stating point: https://github.com/nathanpc/Build.prop-Editor

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my app. Don't forget that it's also open source: https://github.com/nathanpc/Build.prop-Editor

Comment: Thanks guys, was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

yes the ROOT permission is required and you can get the root access by adding following lines

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`

for more details follow the below link
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/