# Change device name programmatically in android

Tags: android, programmatically-created, device-name

I need to change my phone device name **not** the bluetooth name.

I need to change the one which we get by  doing this,

`android.os.Build.MODEL;`

Current Output: `H30-U10`

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267429/which-properties-of-android-os-build-are-fixed

Comment: You need root permissions on your Phone. When you have it, you can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407289/programmatically-edit-the-properties-of-build-prop-on-android

Comment: thanx :) ... but m looking for a solution for all devices

Comment: Without the root permission  there is no chance to do ist

Answer (score 1):

You can access the devices model name manufacturer but you are not supposed to change it.
The only way to do so is "ROOTING" the Device.

Answer (score -2):

Try to do below -

```
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

void ChangeDeviceName(){
     Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename before: "+bluetoothAdapter.getName(); //before
     bluetoothAdapter.setName("name_what_you_want");
     Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename after: "+bluetoothAdapter.getName(); //after

 }
```

Comment: i need to change device name not the bluetooth name please