# Hide navigation bar on rooted android device

Tags: android, navigationbar, kiosk, kiosk-mode, rooted-device

I have a custom rooted android tablet working on Android M version. We built a kiosk application and next step is removing navigation bar completely, while our application is working. Also, when administrator close our application, navigation bar should appear again.

Before asking this question, I researched on Internet and find a lot of people have this problem. However, answers to theirs question were generally, making application to work in full-screen mode or in immersive full-screen mode.
These answers didn't help me at all, because user still can fling on screen and navigation bar would show again. These solutions are probably the best that can be done with an unrooted device, but in my case I need a better solution and my device is **rooted**.

Also, I saw this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055487/6508716), but after using this command my desktop went black, and couldn't reboot android system again. Happily I have recovery USB so my device is working again. :)

I found another answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407289/programmatically-edit-the-properties-of-build-prop-on-android), and like others, didn't help me because I need to reboot system after adding line of code (qemu.hw.mainkeys = 1). Also, solution that I looking for is fully dynamical and done by code.

I am really convinced that this isn't mission impossible, because we had old tablet (also rooted) with button in back, which can hide and show navigation bar without rebooting it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with your problem, but provide a little more information.
The company im working for is using devices in kiosk mode, but we have custom android devices from a hardware producer, which provides a custom HAL interface. We can set the kiosk mode via that interface.

My guess is it cant be done easily, if it was easy, we would have not gone that way. Hope it helps.

Comment: I was convinced that this is possible when device is rooted. Our device is pretty unknown, we only know who is manufacturer, but there isn't other useful info. So I think we gonna ask them, like you said, for custom interface. I thought that we could solve this on developer side, without inclusion of hardware producer.